# Bootstrap modal not opening when coming to the page from an internal link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't come up with a better title, sorry!

The homepage of my Rails 4 app is a grid of images that open a modal on click, everything works fine when I load the website for the first time. If go to the profile page and then press the Home button on the navbar or the "Back to Home" on my profile the modals don't come up anymore, clicking on the thumbnails just adds the '#' to the URL without anything happening.

The only thing that the two links have in common is that both of them are a 'link_to root_path', but I can't see how that could break the modals.

My bootstrap gems:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'  
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

Here's my modal partial (I also tried to just past the code in my index without rendering a partial but same issue)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:40%; min-width: 300px">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="modal-image" style="float: left;" >
        </div>

        <div class="modal-infos" style="padding-left: 10px;float: left;">
        </div>  

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my js function

```
$(function() {
    $('.pop').click(function(){
    $('.modal-image').empty();
    $('.modal-infos').empty();
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    var price = $(this).attr("price");
    var location = $(this).attr("location");
    var heading = [title, " (", price, "€)"].join('')
    $('.modal-title').html(heading);
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-image');
    var infos = ["<li>Location: ", location, "</li><br><li>Price: ",price,"€</li><br><br>"].join('')
    $(infos).appendTo('.modal-infos');
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have turbolinks enabled, you need to make sure the jQuery function you wrote is also triggered on `page:load` event.

Comment: @eugen I just read your reply and disabling Turbolinks did fix the issue so that's the problem. How do I go on about triggering the function on every page:load? The function is in a js file under assets/javascripts/, I tried renaming it 'dealsmodal' and then call "$(dealsmodal);" in my application.html.erb but it doesn't work. I'll keep turbolinks off for now since there's really little to no navigation on the website, but I'd still like to understand for future reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to eugen for putting me on the right track by mentioning the jQuery issue with turbolinks. To fix the problem I declared a "ready" variable in my assets/javascripts/dealsmodal.js, set it equal to my script and then called .on('page:load', ready) like this:

```
var ready;
ready = function dealsmodal(){
    $("body").on("click", '.pop', function(){

    ... function goes here

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

If for some reason you don't want to do this, you can always disable turbolinks from assets/javascripts/application.js by removing `//= require turbolinks`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the public method `show` to open the `modal`.

```
$(function() {
$('.pop').click(function(){
. . . . . 
$('#myModal').modal("show");
});
```

});

Comment: Still the same issue, if I got to my profile and then back on the homepage the modals don't show up even though they do when I load the website the first time.

Comment: Yes, the modal does work, it only breaks if I click on a different page and then come back to the homepage. In that case it doesn't work anymore. If I reload the page it works again though. That's the issue.

Comment: check whether the event is bound correctly using `$._data($(".pop")[0],"events")`. And also try the `delegate` event `$("body").on("click",".pop",function(){......})`...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Try to this

Comment: How should I implement this in my code? Using an if? By just replacing my show method with this it breaks on the homepage as well.

Comment: it would help if you gave a bit more on what you are doing. and you could write a much better answer to help out those of us that are still learning